# Why an affine morphism is separated?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm working on the basic property of affine morphism that they are all separated.
The [proof](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S5) on stacks project uses this [lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KP) but I want to find a direct method.
Here is my attempting:
for an affine morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of schemes, cover $Y$ with open affines $V_i$, and put $U_i=f^{-1}(V_i)$ which is an open affine covering of $X$ . Now we can naturally factor the diagonal morphism as $X\rightarrow\coprod U_i \rightarrow \coprod U_i \times_{V_i}U_i \rightarrow X\times _Y X$. But I can't figure out why the last morphism is closed immersion(is it?).
And does anyone have a brief proof in other ways?

Comment: Shouldn't the first morphism go the other way ($\coprod_i U_i \to X$)?

Comment: @DanielHast  Could you explain how to prove this by your morphism? Using your morphisms I get a 'Cartesian' graph which the upper horizontal arrow is separated, and how can I proof the bottom horizontal arrow is separated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cover $Y$ with affine opens $\def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}\Spec B$: then $$f^{-1}(\Spec B)\times_Y f^{-1}(\Spec B) = f^{-1}(\Spec B)\times_{\Spec B} f^{-1}(\Spec B)=\Spec A\times_{\Spec B}\Spec A$$ cover $X\times_Y X$.
Since a morphism of affine schemes is separated, we have that $\Delta_{X/Y}: X\to X\times_Y X$ is locally a closed immersion on each of these sets. As the condition of being a closed immersion is affine-local on the target, we see that $\Delta_{X/Y}:X\to X\times_Y X$ is a closed immersion and thus $X\to Y$ is separated.

Comment: Didn’t you also use that the diagonal is affine?

Comment: @user128787 I don't think so? Could you say a few more words about why you think I did?

Comment: yes. you use an implication, namely, that local on the target means that if I have the closed immersion property for an (open affine) cover then it holds globally. But local on the target has a slightly different definition, for instance check https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KN . Now, I know the question was accepted but it would be nice to fill this gap, even in the form of a link to another question

Comment: @user128787 Fine, "affine-local" on the target. Happy?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we can prove the locality of separable property: Assume $Y$ can be covered by open $V_i$, and $U_i=f^{-1}(V_i)$. If$f: X \rightarrow Y$ is separated when restricted to each $U_i$, then f itself is separated.